# Limits of integration in a double integral after changing the coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I do not understand why low limit is $u=-rw$, and upper limit is $w$. It is from paper Appendix C of [On the joint statistics of stable random processes](http://m.iopscience.iop.org/1751-8121/44/43/435101/article) by  K. I. Hopcraft and E Jakeman.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

The original domain of integration was bounded by the lines $x=0$ and $x'=0$. In the new coordinates $u,w$ their equations become $u+rw =0 $ and $w+ru=0$. Hence, the limits for $u$ would become $u=-rw$ and $u=-w/r$.

However, the author also exploits some symmetry of the integrand: $x$ and $x'$ are interchangeable.  We can cut the domain along $x=x'$ and double the integral. The line $x=x'$ corresponds to $u+w=0$ in new coordinates. Thus, I think the limit should be $u=-w$ rather than $u=w$. Probably a typo.